# Rails Active Storage render tiny image as base64

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to take an image that has already been uploaded and render the image as a small variant, then output that as a base 64 string.

I cannot seem to get the transformed image, I keep getting the original unprocessed image when I try this:

```
image.attachment.variant( resize_to_fill: [10, 10], convert: :png ).processed.blob.open do |tempfile|
  puts 'data:image/png;base64,' + Base64.strict_encode64(tempfile.read)
end
```

This is returning the data as the full image, not the 10x10 tiny square image. It seems like calling `.blob` on it returns the original image and not the processed one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  variation = ActiveStorage::Variation.new(resize_to_fit: [10, 10])

  image.open do |input|
    variation.transform(input, format: "png") do |output|
      puts 'data:image/png;base64,' + Base64.strict_encode64(output.read)
    end
  end
```